# Error "Table has no columns." Does anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-google-charts

Error "Table has no columns."

It's not returning the API data in the React-google-Charts chart and I can't find the error, anyone to help me? I already broke my head here... It's a Column chart and it's already in the required format.

default model:

```
export const data = [
    ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" }],
    ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"], // RGB value
    ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"], // English color name
    ["Gold", 19.3, "gold"],
    ["Blue", 21.45, "color: #0592FF"],
    ["Oranje", 21.45, "color: #FF494C"],
    ["Brown", 21.45, "color: brown"],
    ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"],
     // CSS-style declaration
  ];
```

Returning on the console:

```
[
    [
        "Solicitante",
        "Quantidade",
        {
            "role": "style"
        }
    ],
    [
        [
            "deisemorais",
            18,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "moisesmoura",
            5,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "elissonsilva",
            7,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "wellingtonreis",
            2,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "josecfilho",
            2,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "wisleycouto",
            2,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "laireborges",
            2,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "marcelobento",
            7,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "rosaniaxavier",
            2,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "rafaelalfarone",
            1,
            "#e5e4e2"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Follow the code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ColumnChart } from "./components/graficos-modelos/ColumnChart/ColumnChart";
import api from "./service/api";




const App = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api();
        const data = response.data;
        // console.log(data);
        const solicitantes = {};
     
        data.body.forEach(element => {
          const solicitante = element["SOLICITANTE"];
          
          if (solicitante in solicitantes) {
            solicitantes[solicitante] += 1;
          } else {
            solicitantes[solicitante] = 1;
          }
        });
      
        const dataForChart = [['Solicitante', 'Quantidade', { role: "style" }]].concat(
          Object.entries(solicitantes).map(([solicitante, value]) => [[ solicitante, value, "#e5e4e2" ]])
        );
        
         setChartData(dataForChart);
         console.log(dataForChart);



        if (dataForChart[0].length >= 2) {
          setChartData(dataForChart);
        } else {
          console.error("Table has no columns.");
        }


      }catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
  
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Grafics in React</h1>

      <ColumnChart  data = {chartData} />
    </div>
  );
};




export default App;
```

```
        if (dataForChart[0].length >= 2) {
          setChartData(dataForChart);
        } else {
          console.error("Table has no columns.");
        }
```

I put this snippet in the code to see if it found any errors but it did not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the code snippet and done some refactor with the code. Please have a look on it.

Issues -

- There is no body key inside data object.
- Second the logic `const solicitante = element['SOLICITANTE'];` can be replaced to `const solicitante = element[0];`

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';

const ColumnChart = () => {
  const data = [
    ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'], // RGB value
    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'], // English color name
    ['Gold', 19.3, 'gold'],
    ['Blue', 21.45, 'color: #0592FF'],
    ['Oranje', 21.45, 'color: #FF494C'],
    ['Brown', 21.45, 'color: brown'],
    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2'],
  ];

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const solicitantes = {};

        data.forEach((element) => {
          const solicitante = element['SOLICITANTE'];
          if (solicitante in solicitantes) {
            solicitantes[solicitante] += 1;
          } else {
            solicitantes[solicitante] = 1;
          }
        });

        const dataForChart = [
          ['Solicitante', 'Quantidade', { role: 'style' }],
        ].concat(
          Object.entries(solicitantes).map(([solicitante, value]) => [
            solicitante,
            value,
            '#e5e4e2',
          ])
        );
        setChartData(dataForChart);
        console.log(dataForChart);

        if (dataForChart[0].length >= 2) {
          setChartData(dataForChart);
        } else {
          console.error('Table has no columns.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Chart
        chartType="ColumnChart"
        width="100%"
        height="400px"
        data={chartData}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ColumnChart;
```

Please find the image attached below which I reproduced after changes.
[image: Column Chart Graph]
Hope this will help you!

Regards